# Reestablish Internet over wifi w/o rebooting

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless

**Problem**:
Internet over wifi connection turns off several times a day. Environment:

- desktop, **Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS**
- wifi external adapter "**Netis**", driver **RTL8812AU**

When I lose my Internet connection wifi connection itself is on. At the same time, my other computer under Windows 10, as well as mobile phone both, have Internet over wifi. I have a Docker swarm running so I also try turning off Docker completely (service docker stop command).

I usually try changing wifi networks, turning off and on wifi adapter, unplugging wifi adapter, turning on and off wifi router, reinstalling the driver.
Nothing helps, only **rebooting** the desktop works. After I reboot my desktop Internet is immediately on.

But I **don't want to reboot** my PC each time I lose Internet: rebooting and starting my environment takes at least 5 minutes.

**Question**:

- is there a magic bash command (probably starting with IP... or net... or just n..) to reset the software that is failing to establish my Internet connection w/o rebooting?

Comment: Did you try `systemctl restart network-manager`?

Comment: Read `man nmcli` and do something like `nmcli con up id Foo`. See `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` for a tool.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.